# Splitting and ordering the class c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class like

```
Class Foo
{
 public string info { get; set; };
 public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, info is like :

```
id=2&pid=6
id=2&pid=6&cid=7
id=2
```

Now, I want to sort it based on the count of parameters (after spliting by &)

so, it should be

```
id=2&pid=6&cid=7
id=2&pid=6
id=2
```

But, I have a list of properties to a class.

The code I wrote is :

```
private List<Foo> FuncADesc(List<Foo> listObj)
        {           
            Dictionary<string, int> di1 = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < listObj.Count; i++)
            {
                Dictionary<string,string> diTemp =  GetInfo(listObj[i].info);
                if (diTemp != null)
                {
                    di1.Add(listObj[i].info, diTemp.Count);
                }
            }

            var list = di1.Keys.ToList();
            list.Sort(); // I want to sort by Descending

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                listObj[i].info = list[i];
                listObj[i].name =  // ??? //
            }

            return listObj;
        }

//Gets the dictionary after splitting by '&'        
private Dictionary<string, string> GetInfo(string Info)
       {
            Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = null;
           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Info))
           {
               NameValueCollection parse1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Info);
               dict1 = parse1.Cast<string>()
                   .Select(s => new {Key = s, Value = parse1[s]})
                   .ToDictionary(dictElement => dictElement.Key.ToLowerInvariant(),
                       dictElement => dictElement.Value.ToLowerInvariant());
           }
           return dict1;
       }
```

I want to return listObj but the name and info gets exchange. Is there some easy way or can you point, where can I change ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use LINQ to do something as simple as this:

```
private List<Foo> FuncADesc(List<Foo> listObj)
{
    return listObj.OrderByDescending(x => x.info.Count(c => c == '&')).ToList();
}
```

`OrderByDescending` allows you to order the items in a descending fashion. This method uses the number of `&` characters within the `info` property of each item as the sort by value.

Comment: @demostack, consider marking this as an answer if it solved your problem